# visual studio c++ cannot open any source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been using visual studio for my unreal projects for some time now.
But when i try to code something in vs i get the error "cannot open source file".
I have a very basic c++ code;

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

when i debug this code i get the error that almost every header file(435 header files) like float.h, string.h, time.h etc. cannot open.

[image]

When i try compiling the code using gcc i get another error but when i use g++ i get no error.

[image]

So i'm assuming i need to change debug options of visual studio. I've tried buy i couldn't figure that out.
How can i make visual studio run the code properly?

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong compiler? you say that you used gcc to compile a C++ file but gcc is used to compile C files only maybe check your configuration?

Comment: C code for the most part is valid c++ code but not vice versa

Comment: Check the File extension on your main file

Comment: You probably need to change the windows sdl setting, it's probably set to a sdk that isn't installed

Comment: Project/Properties/General/Windows SDK Version. What does that say?

Comment: @john Windows SDK Version: 10.0.19041.0

Comment: @Mintybits i don't know what to check in configurations. I've tried different configurations but still getting the same error.

Comment: @yesil Mine says Visual Studio 2022 (v143). I also have the option Visual Studio 2019 (v142). Do you have either of those versions available? What version of Visual Studio are you using? Have you installed any standalone versions of the Windows SDK?

Comment: @john there is 2 option for sdk 10.0 and 10.0.19041.0 or inherit from parent project. i'm using visual studio community 2022. I don't think i installed any standalone windows sdk.

Comment: i uninstall the visual studio and re-install it but still the same error. i don't understand i can use g++ to compile, i also have qt creator which is works fine with c++ but visual studio raise this error even efter re-install

Comment: @yesil 10.0.19041.0 is the correct version I think. But maybe you don't have it installed. Start the Visual Studio Installer, click Modify and check if the Windows 10 SDK is installed (it's under 'Desktop development with C++'). If that doesn't help try looking at the linked duplicates. You are certainly not the only person that has had this problem.

Comment: @john i've clicked modify and yes Windows 10 SDK is installed. I gave up, i'll continue using qt creator :( Thanks for your help.